# I can't create self-extract file with WINRAR because Defender says it's a trojan named Wacatac

Tags: windows, executable, winrar, self-extracting

I'm trying to create a self-extract EXE to run my installer program, which is conformed by 3 files so I need to pack it for distribution.

The problem is that once the file is created using WinRAR, it's automatically deleted by Windows Defender because it thinks it's a trojan named Wacatac.

What can I do about it?? I can't find any info on this trojan to know what to do to avoid this.

Answer (score 7):

Fixed - I had to switch compression format to ZIP instead of RAR, this way Windows Defender no longer identifies the file as a virus/trojan.

Answer (score 0):

delete all files include folder then try again:
TEMP
%TEMP%